# Injectable on service is mandatory in angular 12

Tags: angular, dependency-injection, angular12

I'm trying to understand `@injectable` vs `@Inject`. Found many articles on it, and its best practice to use @Injectable on Service.

But I believe these two snippet(UserService) should behave same.

```
import { Inject, Injectable } from "@angular/core"

export class NewUserService {
  constructor() {
    console.log('NewHerorService')
  }
}

export class UserService {
  constructor(@Inject(NewUserService) private newUserService: NewUserService) {
    console.log('test')
  }
}

**VS** 

@Injectable()
export class UserService {
  constructor(private newUserService: NewUserService) {
    console.log('test')
  }
}
```

And this is working fine(both behaving same) in Angular 8.

But the same thing in Angular 12 giving error:

> Error in src/app/app.module.ts (15:15) The class 'UserService' cannot
> be created via dependency injection, as it does not have an Angular
> decorator. This will result in an error at runtime.
>
> Either add the @Injectable() decorator to 'UserService', or configure
> a different provider (such as a provider with 'useFactory').

Sample links
[Angular 8](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-services-dependencyinjection-cpewne?file=src%2Fapp%2Fuser.service.ts)
[Angular 12](https://stackblitz.com/edit/base-angular-12-app-8tjupj?file=hero.service.ts)

**Update:** After digging some more into it, found if I set `"enableIvy": false` in `.tsconfig.json` of angular 12 version, then it not throws any error and works same as angular 8.

But still don't know why?

Comment: Are you declaring or providing UserService to the related module?

Comment: Yes, in both versions these are added in Appmodule's providers.

Comment: Updated my question with some more information.

Answer (score 0):

The difference between Inject and Injectable:

**Inject**

The Inject decorator allows you to define what provider do you want to be used for the injection. In the example bellow (taken from [Angular Dependency Injection page](https://angular.io/guide/dependency-injection-in-action)), the BROWSER_STORAGE is used as the provider for the Storage service.

```
import { Inject, Injectable, InjectionToken } from '@angular/core';

export const BROWSER_STORAGE = new InjectionToken<Storage>('Browser Storage', {
  providedIn: 'root',
  factory: () => localStorage
});

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class BrowserStorageService {
  constructor(@Inject(BROWSER_STORAGE) public storage: Storage) {}
}
```

**Injectable**

The Injectable decorator allows to define a class as Injectable, meaning you can Inject it on another component or service. Note the if you inject the service like

```
constructor(private storage : Storage){}
```

The default behavior of Angular is to instanciate using `new Storage()`

To learn more about providers see the [Angular Dependency providers page](https://angular.io/guide/dependency-injection-providers)

Feel free to ask for clarification if needed!

Comment: I agree with difference bw these two, my point was in angular 8,without adding injectable decorator on service it was working fine, but not in angular 12.